# How to convert integer to binary string in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm writing a number converter. How can I convert a integer to a binary string in C# WITHOUT using built-in functions (`Convert.ToString` does different things based on the value given)?

- Binary -> Sign magnitude
- Binary -> One's complement
- Binary > Two's complement

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Almost all computers today use two's complement representation internally, so if you do a straightforward conversion like this, you'll get the two's complement string:

```
public string Convert(int x) {
  char[] bits = new char[32];
  int i = 0;

  while (x != 0) {
    bits[i++] = (x & 1) == 1 ? '1' : '0';
    x >>= 1;
  }

  Array.Reverse(bits, 0, i);
  return new string(bits);
}
```

That's your basis for the remaining two conversions. For sign-magnitude, simply extract the sign beforehand and convert the absolute value:

```
byte sign;
if (x < 0) {
  sign = '1';
  x = -x;
} else {
  sign = '0';
}
string magnitude = Convert(x);
```

For one's complement, subtract one if the number is negative:

```
if (x < 0)
  x--;
string onec = Convert(x);
```

Answer (score 20):

Simple soution:

```
IntToBinValue = Convert.ToString(6, 2);
```

Comment: This is by far, the most straightforward answer I found!

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work for unsigned types...

Answer (score 6):

At least part of the answer is to use `decimal.GetBits(someValue)` to convert the decimal to its binary representation.

`BitConverter.GetBytes` can be used, in turn, on the elements returned from `decimal.GetBits()` to convert integers into bytes.

You may find the [`decimal.GetBits()` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.getbits.aspx) useful.

I'm not sure how to go from bytes to decimal, though.

**Update:** Based on Author's update:

`BitConverter` contains methods for converting numbers to bytes, which is convenient for getting the binary representation. The `GetBytes()` and `ToInt32()` methods are convenient for conversions in each direction. The `ToString()` overloads are convenient for creating a hexadecimal string representation if you would find that easier to interpret as 1's and 0's.

Comment: if Bitconverter.GetBytes can turn bits back into bytes, then to go from bytes to ints it's just BitConverter.GetInt32(byte[] bytes)

Comment: @Jimmy - Thanks. The missing link for me is understanding how to convert to the `decimal` type from an array of bytes or an array of Int32.

Answer (score 5):

```
   var a = Convert.ToString(4, 2).PadLeft(8, '0');
```

Answer (score 2):

### Simple .NET 8+ Version

Starting with .NET 8 the [binary format specifier (B)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#BFormatString) was (*finally*) introduced, rendering any extra function to do the conversion (built-in or custom) obsolete (well, unless you want to do something very specific like adding underscores between each byte or nibble for example). It's simply part of the [standard numeric format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings) for the default `ToString()` methods of integral numeric types now:

```cs
int i = 42;
string binary = i.ToString("B"); // 101010

int j = 0x0f0f;
// you can specify the number of digits in the result string, for example 16:
string itsSoSimpleNow = $"{j:B16}"; // 0000111100001111

// this was not possible with Convert.ToString(...) before
ulong k = ulong.MaxValue;
string evenUlongsWorkFinally = k.ToString("B"); // 11...11
```

You can use `B` or `b` for the specifier, it makes no difference :)

**If you're stuck with an older .NET version for now (or really want to go custom)**

I haven't actually seen an easy ASCII based solution so far, so here's one:

```cs
public static string ToBinaryString(ulong u)
{
    Span<byte> ascii = stackalloc byte[64];
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
    {
        // we want the MSB to be on the left, so we need to reverse everything
        // other than that we simply grab the ith bit (from the LSB) 
        // and simply OR that to the ASCII character '0' (0x30).
        // if the bit was 0 the result is '0' itself, otherwise
        // if the bit was 1 then the result is '0' | 1 (0x30 | 1) which 
        // yields 0x31 which is also conveniently the ASCII code for '1'.
        ascii[63 - i] = (byte)((u & (1uL << i)) >> i | '0');
    }
    return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ascii);
}
```

the example above uses `ulong` (partially because that doesn't work with the `Convert.ToString(..., 2)` approach, at least not on .NET 7), but you can use any other integer type as well. Just be sure to cast your value to the corresponding unsigned type first as we don't want signed shifts here. Obviously you may have to change the sizes to the bit sizes of your type. So for `Int32` you'd use this code:

```cs
public static string ToBinaryString(int value)
{
    // note the cast to unsigned here.
    // we don't want any funny negative values in here.
    // the result will be the two's complement binary representation of negative values
    uint u = (uint)value; 
    Span<byte> ascii = stackalloc byte[32];
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    {
        ascii[31 - i] = (byte)((u & (1u << i)) >> i | '0');
    }
    return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ascii);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's mine:
(The upper part convert 32-char binary string to 32-bit integer, the lower part convert 32-bit integer back to 32-char binary string).
Hope this helps.

```
        string binaryString = "011100100111001001110011";
        int G = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < binaryString.Length; i++)
            G += (int)((binaryString[binaryString.Length - (i + 1)] & 1) << (i % 32));

        Console.WriteLine(G); //‭7500403‬
        binaryString = string.Empty;

        for (int i = 31; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            binaryString += (char)(((G & (1 << (i % 32))) >> (i % 32)) | 48);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(binaryString); //00000000011100100111001001110011
```

Comment: Minor bug fix for leftmost character of binary string for negative number.  Should be `(uint)G & (1` instead of `G & (1`. It will looks like `binaryString += (char)((((uint)G & (1 << (i % 32))) >> (i % 32)) | 48);`  Without bug fix, it still works fine for positive number.

Answer (score 0):

This is an unsafe implementation:

```
    private static unsafe byte[] GetDecimalBytes(decimal d)
    {
        byte* dp = (byte*) &d;
        byte[] result = new byte[sizeof(decimal)];
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(decimal); i++, dp++)
        {
            result[i] = *dp;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

And here is reverting back:

```
    private static unsafe decimal GetDecimal(Byte[] bytes)
    {
        if (bytes == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("bytes");

        if (bytes.Length != sizeof(decimal))
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("bytes", "length must be 16");

        decimal d = 0;
        byte* dp = (byte*)&d;
        byte[] result = new byte[sizeof(decimal)];
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(decimal); i++, dp++)
        {
            *dp = bytes[i];
        }
        return d;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can construct the representations digit by digit from first principles.

Not sure what built-in functions you don't want to use, but presumably you can construct a string character by character?

1. Start with the highest power of two greater than the number.
2. Push a "1" into your string.
3. Subtract that power of two from your number.
4. Take the next-lowest power of two.  If you've reached one-half, stop.  You're done.
5. If the number that's left is greater than this power of two, go back to step 2.  If not, push a "0" into the string and go back to step 4.

For one's complement and two's complement, [calculate those with an additional step](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement).

Or is this way too basic for what you need?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an elegant solution:

```
// Convert Integer to binary and return as string
private static string GetBinaryString(Int32 n)
{
    char[] b = new char[sizeof(Int32) * 8];

    for (int i = 0; i < b.Length; i++)
        b[b.Length-1 - i] = ((n & (1 << i)) != 0) ? '1' : '0';

    return new string(b).TrimStart('0');
}
```