# How can I convert a byte into a string of binary digits in C#?

Tags: c#, string, byte, type-conversion

I am trying to convert a byte into a string of binary digits - not encoded, just as it is, i.e. if the byte = 00110101 then the string would be "00110101".

I have searched high and low, and everything I find is either relating to getting the ASCII or UTF or whatever value of the byte, or converting a character into a byte, neither of which is what I want. Just doing ToString() gives me the int value.

Maybe i'm missing something obvious, and I understand this is a fairly rare case. It must be possible without some crazy loop which iterates through, surely?

(I'm sending the string over bluetoothLE to a rotating shop display cabinet to program it)

edit: here's some code:

```
DateTime updateTime = DateTime.Now;
byte dow = (byte)updateTime.DayOfWeek;
Debug.WriteLine(dow.ToString());
```

If I break and inspect 'dow', it shows as '3' (it's wednesday), not 00000011 as I would have expected. I just tried BitConverter as suggested below, but that still returns '3'.

Comment: Post your code. What type is byte?

Comment: Try using BitConverter http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: posible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702216/how-to-convert-integer-to-binary-string-in-c http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581674/converting-bytes-to-a-binary-string-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `Convert.ToString()` but specify a base, in this case because it's binary, base 2.

However, you'll also need to pad to the number of bits, because it will cut off 0 digits, so `00000001` would end up as `1`.

Try this:

```
Convert.ToString(theByte,2).PadLeft(8,'0');
```