# C# How convert short[] to bool[]?

Tags: c#, arrays, boolean, short

```
short[] sBuf = new short[2];
sBuf[0] = 1;
sBuf[1] = 2;

bool[] bBuf = new bool[sBuf.Length * 16];
Buffer.BlockCopy(sBuf, 0, bBuf, 0, sBuf.Length * 2);

Desired result value  
sBuf[0] = 1
bBuf[0] = true, bBuf[1] = false, bBuf[2] = false, bBuf[3] = false...
sBuf[0] = 2
bBuf[16] = false, bBuf[17] = true, bBuf[18] = false, bBuf[19] = false...
```

But can not be converted correctly.
I want to convert from short [] to bool [], but I don't know how.

Comment: When should the `bool` element be `true`?

Comment: @cat: a question to save me some brain cycles :)

Comment: @cat So you want to turn -1, one of the two commonly used values for true, into false? It's good to ask the question and let the OP decide. And based on dasblinkenlight's accepted answer, your guess would have been as wrong as my guess.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming that each `bool` represents a bit from its corresponding `short` (which is presumably why you multiplied the size by 16) you can do the conversion as follows:

```
bBuf = sBuf
    .SelectMany(s => Enumerable.Range(0, 16).Select(i => (s & (1<<i)) != 0))
    .ToArray();
```

The idea is to construct 16 booleans for each `short` by calling [`Enumerable.Range`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), masking the number with `(1 << i)`, and comparing the result to zero.

Comment: Build errors occur.

CS0019 '&' Operator cannot be applied to operands of type 'short' and 'bool'

Comment: @Hoony I edited the answer after you copied the code. A pair of parentheses was missing. Please try again.

Comment: @Hoony you should use updated answer with brackets around `s & (1<<i)` actually you can remove inner brackets: `i => (s & 1 << i ) != 0` but it's not that readable

Comment: @dasblinkenlight 
Resolved.
Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Nice approach. You can optimize it a little bit by taking out of SelectMany the call to Enumerable.Range(0, 16) and store it in a variable.

Comment: @fubo dasblinkenlight's answer seems consistent with OP example, even if the question is unclear.

Comment: I'm still not convinced LINQ *isn't* magic. That said, maybe it's just me but I find this really hard to read.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Could you help me understand `(s & (1<<i))` better? I very rarely see `&` instead of `&&`. Additionally, while I read [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1sway8w.aspx) on the `<<` operator I also don't entirely "get" it

Comment: @sab669 Please see [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32297880/335858), it explains how to check if a bit at position `b` is set or not.

Answer (score 4):

From msdn page of [`Convert.ToBoolean`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wh2c31dd(v=vs.110).aspx) it says that every `0` value will be converted to `false` and every non-`0` value to `true` :

```
bool[] bBuf = new bool[sBuf.Length];
for(int i = 0; i < sBuf.Length; ++i )
{
    bBuf[i] = Convert.ToBoolean(sBuf[i]);
}
```

**EDIT :**
Setting your `bool[]` based on bits set in `short` value you can use this :

```
const int BITS_PER_BYTE = 8; // amount of bits per one byte

int elementBitsSize = sizeof(short) * BITS_PER_BYTE; // size in bits of one element in array
bool[] bBuf = new bool[sBuf.Length * elementBitsSize]; // new array size

// iterate through each short value
for ( int i = 0; i < sBuf.Length; ++i )
{
    // iterate through bits in that value
    for( int j = 0; j < elementBitsSize; ++j )
    {
        // assign new value
        bBuf[j + i * elementBitsSize] = Convert.ToBoolean(sBuf[i] & (1 << j));
    }
}
```

[Working example](http://rextester.com/VHUN3065)

Comment: I like this solution as it is, in my opinion, **far** easier to read than the Selected Answer's LINQ solution. That said, this wouldn't work for OP. For the explicit task of "convert short[] to bool[]" it is fine (though I personally like to always use `T.TryParse()` unless I can guarantee the integrity of the data) but since OP is dealing with the individual bits of each `short` to build 16 times more more `bool` values than he has `shorts` this isn't what he's *actually* looking for

Answer (score 1):

```
// Convert short to bool
bool[] bBuf = Array.ConvertAll(sBuf, n => n != 0);

// Convert short to bit representation bool array
bool[][] bBuf= Array.ConvertAll(arr, n =>
{
    bool[] bits = new bool[16];

    for (int index = 0; index < 16; index++)
    {
        bits[index] = (n & (1 << index)) > 0;
    }

    return bits;
});
```